# Setting a value in a variable to NA, conditional on another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, na, conditional-operator

I'm looking to remove the value in a variable if the condition of another variable is satisfied. For instance:

```
df$var1[df$condvar == 0] <- NA
```

The code above works fine, but I need to repeat this for dozens more variables, so `var1` above would change to `var2`, `var3`, etc.. This is always based on the same `condvar`, although for half of the variables the condition is `df$condvar == 1`. It's cumbersome to repeat this line over and over again, and I was wondering if there was a more concise way to code this. Would one of the `apply` functions help, or would I need to create a custom function?

As a reproducible example, I'm looking to avoid the repetitive nature of the code below:

```
ex <- mtcars
ex$mpg[ex$vs == 0] <- NA
ex$disp[ex$vs == 0] <- NA
ex$drat[ex$vs == 0] <- NA
ex$cyl[ex$vs == 1] <- NA
ex$hp[ex$vs == 1] <- NA
ex$wt[ex$vs == 1] <- NA
ex


                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4             NA   6    NA 110   NA 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag         NA   6    NA 110   NA 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8  NA 108.0  NA 3.85    NA 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  NA 258.0  NA 3.08    NA 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout     NA   8    NA 175   NA 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1  NA 225.0  NA 2.76    NA 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360            NA   8    NA 245   NA 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
etc.
```

I'd be perfectly happy if there's one line of code that applies to all variables for which `condvar == 0` and another for those variables for which `condvar == 1`.

Comment: `df$var1[df$condvar == 0, c("var1", "var2", ...)] <- NA`

Comment: This doesn't work. I don't understand how the `, c("var1", "var2", ...)` part of the code would work.

Comment: @Phil: HubertL meant `df[df$condvar == 0, c("var1", "var2", ...)] <- NA`, which works just fine.

Comment: @smci Indeed it does. The answer you have since deleted needed to be amended, but was pointing the right way.

Comment: @HubertL you should post your approach as an answer.  It's better than the proposed ones (much clearer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an attempt that is hopefully not too complex. If you set up the `vars` you want to loop over, and the corresponding `values` you want to be selected for indexing, you can do:

```
vars   <- c("mpg", "disp", "cyl", "hp")
values <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)

ex[vars] <- Map(function(x,y) replace(x, ex$vs == y, NA), ex[vars], vals)

#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4             NA   6    NA 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag         NA   6    NA 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8  NA 108.0  NA 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  NA 258.0  NA 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout     NA   8    NA 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             18.1  NA 225.0  NA 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# ...
```

If you've only got two groups, you could do this simpler via a couple of assignments as @HubertL  and @Phil mentioned in the comments, but using `Map` allows you consider many variables with many possible index values, without ever extending past 3 lines of code.

Comment: Maybe the `mtcars` example in my question would help further understand. The conditional variable doesn't actually change, just the condition (0 or 1). It's the variable that I want changed that differs from line to line.

Comment: @Phil - edited to hopefully match the edited question.

Comment: that works quite well too, and I like that it can be more generalized. I would have never been able to come up with that. :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @HubertL (who is welcome to post this as an answer and I'll upvote) and @smci:

```
ex[ex$vs == 0, c("mpg", "disp", ...)] <- NA
ex[ex$vs == 1, c("cyl", "hp", ...)] <- NA
```

Comment: `dplyr::filter()` is to be avoided, it will reorder the rows according to that split on vs

Answer (score 3):

The dplyr approach using the new experimental `case_when` function will go something like:

```
require(dplyr)

ex <- mtcars
ex <- ex %>%
      mutate(mpg  = case_when(.$vs==0 ~ as.double(NA), TRUE ~ .$mpg)) %>%
      mutate(disp = case_when(.$vs==0 ~ as.double(NA), TRUE ~ .$disp)) %>%
      mutate(cyl  = case_when(.$vs==1 ~ as.double(NA), TRUE ~ .$cyl)) %>%
      mutate(hp   = case_when(.$vs==1 ~ as.double(NA), TRUE ~ .$hp))
```

Notes:

- Hadley said [on 2016-06-27 "case_when() is still somewhat experiment and does not currently work inside mutate(). That will be fixed in a future version."](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/) It took me 40 min to get this code to this point. You get the idea. Once `case_when`works it'll be good. Meanwhile the workaround with `filter()` is below
- You have to use `.$var` to reference the variable on the RHS
- You have to specify the type of NA on RHS, hence all the `as.double(NA)`
- the `TRUE ~ ...` specifies the default clause

Working workaround with `filter()`:

```
ex <- rbind(ex %>% filter(vs==0) %>% mutate(mpg=NA, disp=NA),
            ex %>% filter(vs==1) %>% mutate(cyl=NA, hp=NA) )
```

which has the side-effect of rearranging rows due to the split on `vs`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ifelse(df$var1 == 0, NA, df$var1)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I would still need to repeat the same line again and again.